# Configure Octave for UTF-8 in linux console

Tags: octave

I am not totally sure that I can ask this question here.
If it is inappropriate please tell me to remove it.

I have configure the Octave editor for UTF-8 in Lubuntu Linux.

But I cannot get Greek characters in Octave console.

I can type Greek characters and they displayed correctly, in linux console.

I tried all fonts for octave console from preferences.

I attach a screenshot.

So, the question is: What I can do, to get greek characters in Linux Octave console?

[image: Greek on linx console but not in Octave]

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem on my linux mint 19.3 / octave 5.1.0. I don't know if there's an option to configure octave / readline specifically for utf support when building the package ... but it may be just that you haven't installed appropriate language support. How did you obtain octave and what do you use to change keyboard layouts?

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou `apt-get install octave`. The only greek letters who rendered ok, are "π" to "ω". Small.

Comment: Obviously, this doesn't answer your question, but I've had bad experiences installing via apt before, so I've been installing from source for years now. It's not that difficult and it would be my recommended way of installing octave on linux. `sudo apt build-dep octave` to obtain the relevant dependencies first, then download the latest sources, `./configure --prefix="/path/where/you/want/to/install"`, `make` (possibly with the `-j` option for parallel compilation), `make install`. If you get configuration errors people can help, and this typically flags problems you would have had anyway.